# TypeScript: Enforce generic type constraint in a nested static class

Tags: typescript, types

For the sake of example, consider a minimal linked list class in TypeScript 3.7.5. A `LinkedList<T>` consists of a chain of `ListNode<T>`, where the type variable `T` refers to the same type in both. Also suppose you are using a private static field in `LinkedList` to hide `ListNode`, because it is an irrelevant implementation detail.

```js
class LinkedList<T> {
  private head: ??? = null;
  private tail: ??? = null;

  private static ListNode = class ListNode<T> {
    constructor(
      public val: T | null,
      public next: ListNode<T> | null) {}
  };

  append(item: T): this {
    if (!this.tail) {
      this.tail = {val: item, next: null};
      this.head = this.tail;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = {val: item, next: null};
      this.tail = this.tail.next;
    }
    return this;
  };

  remove(): T {
    if (!this.head || this.head.val === null) {
      throw Error();
    } else {
      const t = this.head.val;
      this.head = this.head.next;
      return t;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I denote the type `???` above? It is not `List.ListNode` or `List.ListNode<T>`. That's not valid TypeScript (at least as of 3.7.5). It is also not `InstanceType<typeof List.ListNode>`. That is a valid type, but it loses the generic parameter `T`, and thus fails to enforce the constraint that the enclosing and nested classes are parametrized by the same type.

Now we modify the class by introducing a dummy `head` and relying on type inference to carry us:

```js
class LinkedList<T> {
  private head = LinkedList.makeNode<T>();
  private tail = this.head.next;

  private static makeNode<T>() {
    return new this.ListNode<T>(null, null);
  }

  private static ListNode = class ListNode<T> {
    constructor(
      public val: T | null,
      public next: ListNode<T> | null) {}
  };

  append(item: T): this {
    if (!this.tail) {
      this.head.next = {val: item, next: null};
      this.tail = this.head.next;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = {val: item, next: null};
      this.tail = this.tail.next;
    }
    return this;
  };

  remove(): T {
    if (!this.head.next || this.head.next.val === null) {
      throw Error();
    } else {
      const t = this.head.next.val;
      this.head.next = this.head.next.next;
      return t;
    }
  }
}
```

Given this code, TypeScript can prove that `remove()` does, in fact, return instances of `T`. On hover-over, VSC suggests that the type of `head` is `ListNode<T>`. How do I express this type explicitly?

Comment: What's the purpose of nesting ListNode inside of LinkedList? What is this line trying to achieve: `private static ListNode = class ListNode<T> { }`

Comment: Please consider making the above code into a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to demonstrate your issue.  Any issues present that don't relate to your question should be eliminated (e.g., `List` is not declared, `ListNode`'s properties are not initialized) so that people answering can focus on the right thing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to make a field to store the *type* of the list node. It also doesn't really need to be a class; an object type is fine. I'd just do this: [[ts playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AOQPYBMIB4AqA+KAXigG8BYAKCigDcBDAGwC4ocBuS6gOwgA9gW8JGky4CAHyhcArgwYcKAXwXVKAYwZ0ECWHC4BrCOiHAxpTlDAAnOPWDQAFhDrpBiFBmz4okmXKJSsvIW1rZ09lDAdHDMusKeZr5BAX7BFJQWdGCQXOgAFHD2ALYsOACULMAOiOZU1FBwAGZQeQCEVYgAdFExZbX19R0I3dEMAST0sYUQRQA0UnwCgXLKFgNDnU4uARs9aQOKUBAMCNDkdevVw3udPPzjkyzTcwv8LKmrF4NXIzE7Pzc7sAVPVFGsoFYIMBpFYuJEriDPhZIUVUDQIHkKqx+vUmi12j8tug+ucBtQqlZUAB3KAAUSslKsmJB1EOx1OOIGalQXCQkX+XSJnUmLO+guc6AFwyFQNF1Eh0NhkVFYLqqsUQA)

```
type ListNode<T> = {
  val: T;
  next: ListNode<T> | null;
};

class LinkedList<T> {
  private head: ListNode<T> | null = null;
  private tail: ListNode<T> | null = null;


  append(item: T): this {
    if (!this.tail) {
      this.tail = {val: item, next: null};
      this.head = this.tail;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = {val: item, next: null};
      this.tail = this.tail.next;
    }
    return this;
  };

  remove(): T {
    if (!this.head) {
      throw Error();
    } else {
      const t = this.head.val;
      this.head = this.head.next;
      return t;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The thing I'm interested in isn't how to write a list. I am specifically interested in how to access the type of the generic class nested in a static field. Given that in the second code snippet `tsc` seems to able able to reason about the type of `head`, it would be very strange if this type was not expressible in TS. Don't you agree?

Comment: Hm, can you even express the type of ListNode itself? What would go here: `static ListNode: ??? = class ...`  I'm confused about the meaning/intent of this nesting in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same question. Clearly, this is a typed expression, and the compiler can reason about its type.

Comment: Not very well, I think :)

Comment: But well enough to know that `remove()` returns a `T` in the second example.